# How to read a 64-bit number in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I have to read a 64-bit number from the keyboard,but I do not know why it does not work.
Could anyone give me an idea?I am working in masm.
This is what i did:

```
 key dq 0
 give_key db "Enter the encryption key (64-bit): " , 0
 formatkey DB "%lld ", 0

procedure PROC NEAR
    push offset give_key
    call printf
    add esp,4
    push offset key
    push offset formatkey
    call scanf
    add esp,8
    ret
procedure ENDP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last space in `formatkey` causes trouble. Do you really need it?

This works for me (`.lib` from Visual Studio 2010 Express):

```
includelib msvcrt.lib

.686
.MODEL flat
EXTERN _printf:proc, _scanf:proc, _exit:proc

.DATA

    key dq 0
    give_key db "Enter the encryption key (64-bit): " , 0
    scanformat DB "%lld", 0
    printformat DB 10, "Entered: %lld", 10, 0

.CODE

procedure PROC NEAR
    push offset give_key
    call _printf
    add esp,4
    push offset key
    push offset scanformat
    call _scanf
    add esp,8
    ret
procedure ENDP

_main PROC

    call procedure

    push dword ptr key + 4          ; High DWORD of 64-bit QWORD
    push dword ptr key + 0          ; Low DWORD of 64-bit QWORD
    push offset printformat
    call _printf
    add esp,12

    push 0
    call _exit

_main ENDP

END _main
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I deleted that space, and now my program read correctly.Thanks for suggestion too, I will use it in the second algorithm that I have to do.Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using x86 assembly, you will have to do two `mov`s, one for the lower 32 bits, and one for the upper. On x64, you can move it in one instruction, which means on 64-bit, the operation is atomic, whereas on x86, it's not.

For instance, on x86:

```
mov dword [eax], low32
mov dword [eax+4], high32
```

And on x64:

```
mov rax, 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: Thank You! I did so, but I still have a problem in the program. I have now tested the program with the debugger and  when I read from the keyboard, if for example I read 111
and I give "enter", the program expects to enter a value and only then move on. And i am using x86 assembly.